# Build an array dynamically in php

Tags: php, arrays

I need that this array become dynamic: (initial output)

```
$data[0] = array('var0');
```

I have a for cycle that returns (after a few conditions) something as a VAR:

```
for($i = 0; $i < N; $i++) 
    {
    (...) END AS var1;
    (...) END AS var2;
    (...) END AS var3;
    (...) END AS varN;
    (...) END AS (...)
    }
```

Expected output after the first cycle:

```
 $data[0] = array('var0','var1');
```

Expected output after the second cycle:

```
 $data[0] = array('var0','var1','var2');
```

And go on (expected final output):

```
 $data[0] = array('var0','var1','var2','var3','varN');
```

How could it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To "push" something onto the end of the array, use the `[]` syntax:

```
$data[0][] = 'something to add to array';
```

E.g.

```
$data[0] = array();
$data[0][] = 'first';
$data[0][] = 'second';
```

`$data[0]` will contain:

```
array('first','second');
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for($i = 0; $i < N; $i++) {
    $data[0][] = 'var' . $i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not prefix the numbers range, for example via [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map):

```
$data[$i] = array_map(function($v) {return 'var' . $v;}, range(0, $i));
```

And if you've got a range inside the range, you can do that, too:

```
$prefix = function($prefix) {
    return function($v) use ($prefix) {
        return $prefix . $v;
    };
};

$map = function($v) use ($prefix) {
    return array_map($prefix('var'), range(0, $v));
}

$data = array_map($map, range(0, $n - 1));
```

Or all at once (compacted):

```
$data = array_map(function($v) {
    return array_map(function($v) { return 'var' . $v;}, range(0, $v));       
}, range(0, $n - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want: [array_push()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php). You can add your vars to your array in your loop then.